# UDP iterative servers C++ code

Tags: c++, sockets, server, udp

This is my server. I want to make iterative server using UDP, but the it's client does not quit and the second one receives the message. This is not an iterative server. Can you tell me  a way so that the new client waits till the first client quits?

------------UDP ITERATIVE SERVER----------

```
#include <iostream>
#include "config.h"
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include "unp.h"
using namespace std; 
int main() {
    int sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    if (sockfd==-1) {
        cout<<"ERROR WHILE CREATING SOCKET"<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        cout<<"SOCKET CREATED SUCCESSFULLY"<<endl;
    }
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_port=htons(4444);
    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    memset(&(server.sin_zero),'\0',8);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    int trybind=bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&server,sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    if (trybind==-1) {
        cout<<"ERROR WHILE BINDING ..."<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    char msg[100],tosend[100];

    if (trybind==0) {
        cout<<"binded successfully"<<endl;}
        while(1) {
            struct sockaddr_in client;   
            socklen_t sizee=sizeof(client);    
            while(recvfrom(sockfd,msg,100,0,(struct sockaddr*)&client,&sizee)) {
                cout<<"CLIENT : "<<msg<<endl;
                cout<<"[CLIENT's PORT NUMBER :]"<<htons(client.sin_port)<<endl ;
                char* clientip[100];
                //socklen_t sizE=sizeof(client);
                //clientip=inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(client.sin_addr), clientip, &sizee);

                cout<<"[CLIENT's IP Address  :] "<<inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr)<<endl;
                if (strcmp(msg,"quit")!=0) {
                    cout<<"SERVER :";
                    cin.getline(tosend,100);
                    cout<<endl;
                    int sen=sendto(sockfd,tosend,100,0,(struct sockaddr*)&client,sizee);  
                }
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

*************client***********

```
#include <iostream>
#include "config.h"
#include "unp.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    if(sockfd==-1) {
        cout<<"ERROR WHILE CREATING SOCKET"<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        cout<<"SOCKET CREATED SUCCESSFULLY"<<endl;
    }
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_port=htons(4444);
    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    memset(&(server.sin_zero),'\0',8);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");    
    while(1) {
        char msg[100],tosend[100];
        cout<<"CLIENT:";
        cin.getline(tosend,100);
        cout<<endl;
        if (strcmp(tosend,"quit")==0) {
            cout<<"quiting"<<endl;
            exit(0);
        }
        socklen_t sizee=sizeof(server);    
        int sen=sendto(sockfd,tosend,100,0,(struct sockaddr*)&server,sizee);
        //struct sockaddr_in client;            
        int rec=recvfrom(sockfd,msg,100,0,(struct sockaddr*)&server,&sizee);    
        cout<<"SERVER : "<<msg<<endl;    
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by iterative server?

Comment: Indenting posted code is fair.

Comment: udp is connectionless so that you can't serialize clients...

Comment: While much of the code could be used in a C program, your program is still C++ and not C. Please edit and change tags accordingly.

Comment: You'd have to program some way for the server to know when the first client had quit (e.g. have the client send an "I'm quitting now" packet of some sort before it exits -- note that the packet might or might not actually make it to the server, and if it didn't, then the server would be stuck).  But the approach is dubious anyway; a server that can only serve one client at a time is a server that is going to appear broken to every other client that is out there wondering why it's not responding.  A better approach would be to design the server to handle multiple clients at once.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I mean that server will do response with only one client at a time, and other client which is connected has to wait till the recent client is closed.

Comment: @Jean I am new to this.I'll be better next time.

Comment: As Jean-Baptiste said, UDP is connectionless. There is no concept of "while a client is connected" in this case, unless you make on on top of UDP.

Comment: It's connectionless but I want to impose a condition so that their no packet loss.

Comment: So why not use TCP?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I want a UDP iterative server in which till the first client quits, other clients have to wait for the first client to quit .i can use TCP but  i want to make an iterative UDP server.any suggestions?

Comment: **EDIT**  @SamiKuhmonen I mean that server will do response with only one client at a time, and other client which wants to communicate server has to wait till the communicating client quits.

Comment: So use TCP. If you want to insist on using UDP you're on your own trying to recreate something that already exists for no apparent reason. It's like wanting to use a dead fish to hit nails when you have a hammer next to you. Only you know how to tell when "a client quits" so implement that somehow if you want to use UDP. We can't help you in that.

Comment: You CAN'T serialize clients in UDP because it's connection less, so that there is no *link* in between two packets received by the server. You may think filtering by IP or something like that, but doing so will not guarantee anything such. Use TCP.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen  Ok thankyou for your time sir.